# Custom field - unable to read value - [<class 'jira.resources.PropertyHolder'>]

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

We have a custom field within jira service desk which holds the organization. Currently I'm trying to return the organization from the issue object returned by my jira search.

However when i try to do this, I just get a class, and i'm unable to see what the object value of the organization is.

tried var() and various other methods, tried .name which works for others, or .value etc.

```py
import sys
from collections import Counter
from jira import JIRA

#Changes the default server to the below server
options = {
    'server': 'myserver',
    }
#Writes the above changes to the JIRA module with the username and password for authentication
jira = JIRA(options,basic_auth=(username,pw))

#Search Query, this can be very similar to the same search query you'll type within Jira
issues_in_proj = jira.search_issues('project=FUD', maxResults=1)

#All issues returned are objects, this means they contain all the fields attached to them.
#They can be accessed via a loop and via the fields varible. e.g issue.fields.summary
for issue in issues_in_proj:
    print issue.fields.customfield_13000
```

I would like it to return the value as almost every other field does.

Comment: The code looks good. Can you check, if the field is null in response object.

i tried your code, and it runs fine.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to get this when the results are returned as a "ResultsList" which is the default.

However you can request the the results are returned as a dict, which is how I've solved this issue.

```
jira.search_issues('project=FSD', maxResults=1,json_result=True)
```

https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=dict

json_result (bool) – JSON response will be returned when this parameter is set to True. Otherwise, ResultList will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use

```
for issue in issues_in_proj:
    print (issue.fields.customfield_13000[0].id)
    print (issue.fields.customfield_13000[0].name)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was necessary to configure the field to be read in all jira projects, because I was trying to read a field that did not belong to the read project.

[Field configured to be used in all projects.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqS90.png)

Comment: Please change the image to display information in english

Answer (score 0):

You can check the attributes of the query and specific field then just extract what you need.

```
YourQuery = jira.search_issues(QUERY, maxResults=0)

for issue in YourQuery:
print(issue.fields.customfield.__dict__)
```

In my case I extracted the data in a dictionary.

```
for issue in jira_issues_Clex_Outflow:
d = {
'CustomName':  issue.fields.customfield.AttributeCustomField
 }
```